# CRM - Transfer list of products from opportunity to order on close opportunity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

When closing an opportunity as won, a workflow will run and create an Order based on some of the fields in Opportunity. We are not currently transferring the product list from opportunity to order. We are aware that there is a default relationship between opportunity and product called 'opportunityproduct'.

We need to know if there is a way to transfer the Products from 'opportunityproduct' to 'orderproduct'. Can this be achieved solely through the use of CRM workflow? Or would we need to create a custom Plugin?

Comment: I don't think you can do that by a workflow. When you create a quote from the opportunity the products get transfered to the quote and when the quote is closed they get pushed to the order, but from opportunity to order I think you need a plugin.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do the plugin?

Comment: Well, you need to link the order back to the opportunity to be able to retrieve all the opportunity products.
Then do a post operation plugin on the create message of opportunity, get all products related to the opportunity and then create them as order products. This is obviously the short version, let me know if you need further support.